# Can an ELM327 OBD-II reader report on anything other than engine trouble codes for a Mini Cooper?

Tags: cel, obd-ii

My car (Mini Cooper S) has a service light and tire pressure light on, so I was expecting my new OBD reader to tell me what they were about, but it just says "0 confirmed emissions-related DTCs received", and no error messages.

Does the sensor (in this case the ELM327) only have access to "check engine" messages or is there a way to read other diagnostic codes?

EDIT: Diagnostics are also said to be stored in the key fob itself. I wonder if those are readable by any OBD-II device, or if that is an unrelated protocol.

Comment: I've edited your title to reflect that the question you are asking is actually quite application-specific.

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't realize that there was that much of a difference between the different devices, etc.

Comment: there isn't necessarily, but there _can_ be--some readers are available that are specifically tailored for one make of vehicle. I have one (VAG-COM) that is tailored for VW/Audi cars and can access multiple computers on the vehicle's CAN-BUS network.

Comment: Good to know. I should see if something similar exists specially for my car.

Comment: What software are you using with the device?

Comment: I am using iPhone/iPad software called [EngineLink](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/engine-link-obd-ii-vehicle/id591557194?mt=8) but would be glad to purchase something else if it would give more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BMW utilizes proprietary tools to access OEM codes. The OBD-II standard only gives you access to the government mandated codes, which would reveal an emission issue. You might have fault codes, but they would only be available to the dealers computer or a knockoff of said computer.

PS Mini and BMW use the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

Manual reset of service light, button A is between the fuel gauge and the 150 MPH marking on the speedo. Information is displayed on the speedo. Ignition off, press and hold button A, turn the ignition key to position 1, after 5 or so seconds the message OIL SERVICE or INSPECTION and "reset" or "re" is displayed, release button and then press and hold button A, after 5 seconds or so "reset" will start to flash, release button A, press and release button A again, new service interval is now displayed, press and release button A and the message "END SIA" is displayed, switch off ignition. This reset applies when the vehicles are due servicing. If the vehicle is not due servicing it will not reset. Tyre pressures for the RunFlat tyres on the Mini Cooper are 30psi. To reset: With all tyres inflated to 30psi, Start the engine, press the tyre reset button next to the handbrake lever until the TPMS lamp on the dash lights up. Drive the vehicle faster then 15mph and the system will reset. The ELM327 when set to read OBD2 will only have software to request OBD2 codes from the engine ECU. If you want to read anything else you will need a scanner that will instruct the ELM327 to request and read and display the system you want.